# Delete and cast. Will delete free the right amount of bytes?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, delete-operator, sockaddr-in, sockaddr

Will delete free the right amount of bytes ?

```
unique_ptr<sockaddr_in> up = make_unique<sockaddr_in>();        
// or unique_ptr<sockaddr_in> up( new sockaddr_in ); ???

/* 
    Some stuff 
    sockaddr and sockaddr_in are two different types of struct and are not relateted 
*/

sockaddr *p = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>( up.release() );

delete p;
```

Comment: Please note that you're deleting a smart pointer. It will be deleted again resulting in undefined behavior. At that point the right about of bytes might be freed. Or your computer might fly away.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld That's not correct.  Please see [`std::unique_ptr::release`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release).

Comment: That will absolutely NOT delete the right amount of bytes (if `sockaddr` and `sockaddr_in` are not the same size) and also will NEVER (even if they are the same size) call the right destructor.

Comment: You are initially using RAII but then dropping that, using reinterpret_cast and cleaning the new object up using a different deleter. How do you expect this would be safe in any way??

Comment: It might do anything. You are firmly into undefined behaviour here. There is no reason to write code like this. Don't.

Comment: What if i cast it to a void pointer ? In C with malloc and free it will work because on the beginning of the allocated space, there is a header with the information of the number of bytes allocated so free(void *) knows how many bytes to free. I don't need to call a destructor for these structs, because they have no constructor respectively a default-constructor.

Comment: @G.M. I didn't read properly. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MarkusFischer they soul e aggregate type which is stricter requirement, but in this case they are

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, `sockaddr` is not a base class of `sockaddr_in` (source [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sockaddr-2), [2](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/645f08975f49441b3e753d8dc5b740cbcb226594/include/uapi/linux/in.h#L237), [3](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/868aabb4708dafdd92aba457edb449bb41eddac8/sys/netinet/in.h#L97)):

```
struct sockaddr {
        ushort  sa_family;
        char    sa_data[14];
};

struct sockaddr_in {
        short   sin_family;
        u_short sin_port;
        struct  in_addr sin_addr;
        char    sin_zero[8];
};
```

Therefore according to [[expr.delete]/p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.delete#3) the behavior of the program is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

> ... if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

---

With that said, in many cases the built-in operator `delete` simply delegates to `free`, which does not need the size, and the program will appear to work as intended (though when coding in C++ we *really* prefer to stay in the realm of defined behavior).

Why not simply let the `unique_ptr` do its job and `delete` the `sockaddr_in` upon destruction?

Answer (score 1):

It would delete `sizeof(sockaddr)` bytes , unless `sockaddr` is base type of `sockaddr_in` and got a virtual destructor. Wherever that would succeed otherwise or not is undefined. After you did `reinterpret_cast`, `sockaddr*` is the static type of pointer. question is , does it have different dynamic type or not.